# Are there anonymized medical records publicly available for research?

Tags: medical

I realize this is kind of a long shot, but I figured I would ask - I'm try to do large scale analysis of medical data for research purposes, but it's exceedingly difficult to get access to medical records in any large quantity.  Is there data available for something like this?

I'm trying to get as complete a set of electronic medical records as possible.  Specifically, I'm looking for information on diagnoses for a variety of conditions.

Data format or source doesn't really matter to me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually medical records are considered to be highly confidential information and protected by various laws. However, many states provide de-identified data on hospital discharges. It usually includes information on diagnosis, treatment and discharge status. Also here http://www.tdi.texas.gov/wc/information/pudfpricelist.html you can find data on Texas workers compensation medical claims.

Also you can buy medical claims data from various sources, e.g. Truven (http://truvenhealth.com/your-healthcare-focus/analytic-research/marketscan-research-databases). Though they are usually pricey.