# Are there any (openly) available data sets for medical coding examples?

Tags: data-request, mimic-iii, medical

Are there any data sets of medical *coding* examples available online?

Eg. Doctor's notes and resulting (correct/accepted) procedure and diagnosis codes for individual encounters or samples of incorrectly coded `ICD10` and `CPT` code sequences/bunches and they are associated with corrected sequences/bunches (by saying, ing medical coders or reviewers).

Or something of the form, for example, of what a medical billing coder might see on a charge review screen. Something like says a dataset where each sample contains

```
[<patient demographics>, <Diagnoses>, <Charges (ie. ICD10 codes and the associated diagnoses)>, etc]
```

I'm aware of the [MIMIC-III](https://mimic.physionet.org/gettingstarted/access/) data set, but need `ICD10` (the latest medical code standard, implemented on 2015-10-01) while the latest version of MIMIC uses `ICD9`. Also aware of [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10301/17538) very similar question, but was hoping that users may have suggestions in this case since the data I need is slightly more specific. Would like to look at differences in what doctors record as diagnoses and procedure codes and what the actual correct/acceptable code combinations should be as edited by a medical coder before the charge was sent to an insurer.

Comment: This information exists primarily in the general practioneers / specialists computer and most likely not anywhere else. E.g. in Europe due to GDPR this is usually not shared with sick funds / insurances. All handling /statistics / anomaly dection is then already based on coded values, AFAIK. You may find patient registries that provide a deeper level of information (than codes) or some other commercial offering of RWD might have that information in other jurisdictions like the US. Hope some others can help you with information on that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this file represents the data you seek: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reymor/meical/master/medical_icd10/data/diseases.xml

Comment: Not quite. Was looking more for datapoints that give a picture of a patient-doctor encounter. Something of the form, for example, of what a medical billing coder might see. Something like say a dataset where each sample is contains `[<patient demographics>, <Diagnoses>, <Charges (ie. ICD10 codes and the associated diagnoses)>, etc]`. This questions' been quiet for some time, but will update it to include this info.